# Asynchronously working of for loop in protractor

Tags: json, for-loop, asynchronous, protractor

when i execute the following code using protractor it works. I am passing nested json to for loop. Because of asynchronously working of for loop it print all values of variable i and reaches to last value because of this it always access last pair of username and password. How can i solve this issue?

```js
var data = require('.../testdata.json');

describe('homepage Test', function() {

  it('candidate login', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://abcxyz.com');
    for (i in data.testdata) {
      element(by.id('tool_btn3')).click();
      console.log(i);
      browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log("Title: " + title)
        if (title === "<page title>") {
          browser.driver.sleep(3000);
          element(by.id('email_input')).sendKeys(data.testdata[i].username);
          element(by.id('pwd_input')).sendKeys(data.testdata[i].password);
          element(by.xpath('//*[@id="signIn_btn"]/div[2]')).click();
          browser.sleep(3000);
          element(by.id('setting_img')).click();
          browser.sleep(2000);
          element(by.id('logout_div')).click().then(function() {
            console.log('success');
          });
        } else {
          console.log("problem");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Priyal. Please be sure to read the guide on how to ask "good" questions ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). It helps everyone to find relevant content and you will get better answers faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that you can't use a `for`-loop with promises. All is async so in the *end it will bite you in the ass*, meaning that the `it` is ready but the test isn't.

Based on you example it would suggest to make a method called for example `logon` (place it in a Page Object or something). It will do the logon and stuff for you. Add an empty promise-container (array) and push the promises in there.

When the `for`-loop is done you can resolve the complete promise-container at once and it will execute all the promises 1 after each other. It will look something like this.

```js
var data = require('.../testdata.json');

describe('homepage Test', function() {

  it('candidate login', function() {
    var promises = [];
    browser.driver.get('https://abcxyz.com');
    for (i in data.testdata) {
      promises.push(expect(logon(data.testdata[i].username, data.testdata[i].password)).to.equal(true));
      promises.push(console.log(i));
    }
    Promise.all(promises);
  });
});

/**
 * Logon
 * @params {string} username
 * @params {string} password
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function logon(username, password) {
  element(by.id('tool_btn3')).click();\
  return browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log("Title: " + title)
    if (title === "<page title>") {
      browser.driver.sleep(3000);
      element(by.id('email_input')).sendKeys(username);
      element(by.id('pwd_input')).sendKeys(password);
      element(by.xpath('//*[@id="signIn_btn"]/div[2]')).click();
      browser.sleep(3000);
      element(by.id('setting_img')).click();
      browser.sleep(2000);
      return element(by.id('logout_div')).click()
        .then(function() {
          return Promise.resolve(true);
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(false);
    }
  });
}
```

If you are using for example Node 7 you can use [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), or use Babel to transpile the code. If you can write TypeScript you also get the `async/await`

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for you response. I hope you now understand how to handle promises in a for loop

Comment: No I don't, just learned it by doing and reading a lot of posts about Protractor. Have you already checked the github page of protractor itself? There are some details and readme files there

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your feedback.