# Find element in grid with pages and click on it using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a grid with pagination enabled and I need to navigate through the pages to find required row and click on it using protractor. I can click on a specific row in the 1st page but if it's not on the first page so I need to click next page and check for the required row.

```
element.all("by.id('value').filter((row) => {
  return row.getText().then((text) => {
    if (text.indexOf(text) != -1) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}).then((rows) => {
  if (rows)
    rows[0].element(by.name('name')).click();
});
```

Below code is running 5 times even if the element is found on 1st page

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
  ( (i) =>{
    console.log('I:'+i);
    element.all("by.id('value').filter((row) => {
      return row.getText().then((text) => {
        if (text.indexOf(someval) != -1) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }).then((rows) => {  
        if(matchingRows.length>0){
     matchingRows[0].element(by.css(this.button)).click();
        return;
      }
    });
  })(i);
next.click();
 }
}
```

Comment: Do a `for` loop to navigate trough pages, in it add a `if` condition, if the element is found then click it and return.

Comment: in for loop how to break element.all promise as I need to use element.all for each iteration in for loop?

Comment: Use the loop for page numbers, the loop should look like this one from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634558/looping-on-a-protractor-test-with-parameters  Another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015191/asynchronously-working-of-for-loop-in-protractor

Comment: Will this loop run through all the pages right? If I have 10 pages and I found the element in 5th page how should I come out of the loop?

Comment: Add an `if` condition, if element is found, click it and `return true;`

Comment: @lauda, please check modified code. return is not working after the click.