# How a asynchronous function wait in a loop

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber framework with protractor 5.2.2. I have a requirement of post something in each location of any account and different accounts having different number of locations.And i am getting this location value from the DB(I have to click on this locations by its name).I have used below code for that.

```
request.query('SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE ID =1', function (loc) {               
    var loc_count=loc.length ;
      var i;    
      for (i=0; i<loc_count; i++){           
          element(by.cssContainingText("span", loc[i].Location_name)).click();
          browser.sleep(4000);
          element(by.css('.post')).sendKeys("test"); 
          element(by.css('.submit')).click();;                               
      } 
});
```

But here the asynchronous functions click()/sendKeys()/sleep() are not waiting.click()/sendKeys()/sleep() are executing for one or two  locations and exit from the for loop and then executing the next feature step. So how can i execute this loop properly for all locations.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your loop ends before even the first element is clicked. You can use `loc.map(function(elem) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But loc.map(function(elem) also not working. click()/sendKeys()/sleep() are not waiting even in the map function.

Comment: I guess you need to >Await< an answer.. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously working of for loop in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015191/asynchronously-working-of-for-loop-in-protractor)

Comment: @rasjani, Its very helpful..Great Thanks.